# A point of clarification on Joda's DateTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I'd like to do something like

```
private DateTime[] importantDates = {
        new DateTime(2013, 6, 15, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(2013, 9, 15, 0, 0)
};
```

Where year is always current year. Does Joda allow for something like this, without calculations?

Example: Right now we are living in 2013. I'd rather not hardcode this value.

For that matter, what i would really like it

```
private DateTime[] importantDates = {
        new DateTime(current_year, 6, 15),
        new DateTime(current_year, 9, 15),
};
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.now().getYear()` will return the current year ([javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#now%28%29)). You might want to use one of the overloaded versions to adjust the time zone for example.

Answer (score 5):

Well the simplest approach would be:

```
int year = new DateTime().getYear();
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[] {
    new DateTime(year, 6, 15, 0, 0),
    new DateTime(year, 9, 15, 0, 0),
};
```

That's not ideal for *instance* variables as it introduces an extra instance variable (`year`) for no good reason, but you could easily put it into a helper method:

```
private final DateTime[] importantDates = createImportantDatesThisYear();

private static DateTime[] createImportantDatesThisYear() {
    int year = new DateTime().getYear();
    return new DateTime[] {
        new DateTime(year, 6, 15, 0, 0),
        new DateTime(year, 9, 15, 0, 0),
    };
}
```

Note that all of this code assumes that you want

Comment: @assylias: Well it introduces an extra instance variable for no reason. It does work though, which it wouldn't in C# where an instance variable initializer can't refer to `this`... will edit.